# Download RPMs and their dependencies for an offline use

Tags: yum

This Command Line have to prepare install all these rmps on my Centos 7.0 :

```
yum install bison gettext glib2 freetype fontconfig libpng libpng-devel libX11 libX11-devel glib2-devel libgdi* libexif glibc-devel urw-fonts java unzip gcc gcc-c++ automake autoconf libtool make bzip2 wget
```

I want to download all these rpms and their dependencies for an offline use .
I will also want to use the same Command Line to install all the rpms on offline .
Someone have an idea how to achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Red Hat you can use a plugin for yum called 'yum-plugin-manager'. You will need to install it first but once installed will allow you to perform the following to download the RPM's and their dependencies.

```
$ yum install --downloadonly  bison gettext glib2 freetype fontconfig libpng libpng-devel libX11 libX11-devel glib2-devel libgdi* libexif glibc-devel urw-fonts java unzip gcc gcc-c++ automake autoconf libtool make bzip2 wget
```

See this document for more detailed instructions. https://access.redhat.com/solutions/10154

Answer (score 0):

As far as I see all those packages are available in DVD. So download a DVD and use it.

To install them you can create own local repo or use rpm command:

```
rpm -i  bison gettext glib2 freetype fontconfig libpng libpng-devel libX11 libX11-devel glib2-devel libgdi* libexif glibc-devel urw-fonts java unzip gcc gcc-c++ automake autoconf libtool make bzip2 wget
```

P.S. If you create local repo and add it in repos directory you will be able to use yum command on the same way as you use it when you are online. Check [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-and-use-yum-repositories-on-a-centos-6-vps) how to make local repo